# Showing 404 in Dynamic web

Tags: java, ajax, xml, servlets

Showing the not found 404. Path is correct i think and no errors are showing.
Let me help with this.

.java file

```
@Path("/foods")
public class FoodService {

    List<Food> foods;
    ArrayList<Food> foodCart = new ArrayList<>();

    public FoodService() {
        foods = FoodController.getFoodList();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Food> getFoodList() {
        return foods;
    }
```

web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
version="3.1">
 <display-name>Food Service</display-name>

 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>food_service</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
 <init-param>
 <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
 <param-value>foodservice</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>food_service</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file></welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

the link i tried to get value : http://localhost:8080/food_service/rest/foods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Servlet Spec 3.1 you're on a fairly modern version of Glassfish.  In that case you're making your life way too hard.  I would recommend either removing your `web.xml` or change it to be basically empty:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

Then, in any package, add the code below.  This tells the container (Glassfish) that you're running a REST application and serves a similar function as the `url-pattern` that you have in your current `web.xml`:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;


@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
    // intentionally empty
}
```

With that, you will call your service with `http://localhost:8080/<webapp name>/rest/foods` where `webapp name` is the name of your web application.

Comment: I changed the way you said. http://localhost:8080/food_service/rest but still showing 404 to above link

Comment: What is your web app name?

Comment: food_service. but I created the package as foodservice. I didn't change the web.xml. I just delete it.

Comment: Then your url is `http://localhost:8080/food_service/rest/foods`.  The package name has nothing to do with the URL in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by replacing the display-name and param-value tag values with the package name where class FoodService is located.

Please refer the [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html) in case of confusions.